# Steam doesn't work on Arch Linux x64

Tags: arch-linux, steam

I have installed all dependencies
I have installed nvidia drivers
But I get this error
please help

```
/home/azamat/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 161: VERSION_ID: unbound variable

/home/azamat/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 161: VERSION_ID: unbound variable

Running Steam on arch  64-bit

/home/azamat/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 161: VERSION_ID: unbound variable

STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)

libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found

libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the latest graphics card drivers? I had a similar problem a couple of weeks back and it was resolved by installing the latest drivers for my card. If that doesn't work I recommend installing PlayOnLinux (front end of Wine) and emulating Steam through that.

Comment: if I install noveau drivers can I play games like DOTA 2, Assassin's creed |||?

Comment: I have installed latest official nvidia drivers (340.96), but it didn't help

Answer (score 5):

I installed lib32-nvidia-.. and it helped

Comment: Thank you! `pacman -S multilib/lib32-nvidia-utils` helped on archlinux